# When do binary functions have non trivial meromorphic homomorphisms and why?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations

We turn our attention to arbitrary meromorphic binary operations $B(x,y): \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

I was considering so called "homomorphism" functional equations of the form $$ F(B(x,y)) = B(F(x), F(y)) $$

Some simple examples include

$$ F(x-y) = F(x) - F(y) $$

Which has meromorphic solutions $F(x) = c*x$ for your choice of complex constant $c$.

$$ F(x/y) = F(x)/F(y) $$

Which has mermorphic solutions $F(x) = x^c$ for your choice of complex constant $c$.

Now here's where things tricky. Suppose we look into

$$ F\left( \frac{1}{a-b} \right)  = \frac{1}{F(a) - F(b)} $$

By setting $a = y + h$, $b = h$ its easy to see then that

$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \ h F \left( \frac{1}{h} \right) = \frac{1}{F'(y)}  $$

Regardless whether the left hand side is well defined or not it clearly does not depend on $y$ at all, so any such $F$ must be piece wise constant and outside of the trivial solution $F(x) = x$ cannot be meromorphic.

### So here's the question:

Under WHAT conditions on the binary operator $B(x,y)$ does the equation

$$ F(B(x,y)) = B(F(x), F(y)) $$

Have a non trivial meromorphic solution $F(x)$?

### Possible Direction:

It's interesting that while $F \left( \frac{1}{a-b} \right)  = \frac{1}{F(a) - F(b)}$ doesn't admit non trivial solutions that the equation $$ F \left( \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b}} \right) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{F(a)} - \frac{1}{F(b)}} $$ DOES admit non trivial solutions, namely $f(x) = cx$

It would seem to me based on all this evidence that $B(x,y)$ having an identity and being associative might be very important.

Comment: $x^c$ can't be made to work for $B(x,y)=x/y$ for complex $c,$ because of branch cuts. It can be made to work for $c$ an integer.

Comment: On the one hand you are completely right, on the other hand, there's a probably a more correct way to state this question so that we can support "naturally multivalued" functions and the problem still remains as a result. I will need some time to think about how to re-ask the question

Comment: Maybe instead of $F$ being just meromorphic, one says that there is a riemann surface defined such that $F$ respects the functional equation OVER the entire riemann surface and then we can safely talk about $x^c$ without considering branch cuts. Except how to define arbitrary binary operations on a riemann surface now remains as a puzzle

Comment: Seems like you want to know something nice about the subspaces of the form $S_z=B^{-1}(z)$ of $\mathbb C^2.$ Just an intuition.